# What is wrong with my node.js + express + socket.io application?

Tags: node.js, heroku, express, socket.io

I had my application set up before so that it was working.  I recently changed the order of a couple things and now it is broken.  I was hoping someone knew the best way to set up a node/express application with socket.io (on heroku). I think I'm missing something because I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is my current app.js that breaks:

```
var express = require('express'), 
    app = express.createServer(express.logger()),
    io = require('socket.io'),
    routes = require('./routes'), 
    chatroom = require('./routes/chatroom'), 
    http = require('http'),
    path = require('path');

io.configure(function () {
  io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]);
  io.set("polling duration", 10);
});

var socket = io.listen(app);

app.configure(function(){
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/room/:chatroom', chatroom.create_room);
app.get('/privateroom/:chatroom', chatroom.create_private_room);

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port);
```

Comment: How is your app breaking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what i have

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path')
  , io = require('socket.io');

var app = express()
  , server = http.createServer(app)
  , io = io.listen(server);

var db = require('./server/db');

/**
 * Config.
 */

    app.configure(function() {
      app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
      app.set('views', __dirname + '/public/views');
      app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
      app.use(express.favicon(__dirname + '/public/images/favicon.ico'));
      app.use(express.logger('dev'));
      app.use(express.bodyParser());
      app.use(express.methodOverride());
      app.use(express.cookieParser('any-text'));
      app.use(express.session({
        secret: 'any-text'
      }));
      app.use(app.router);
      app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    });

    app.configure('development', function() {
      app.use(function(req, res, next){
        res.send(404, 'Sorry, page not found!');
      });
      app.use(express.errorHandler());
    });

/**
 * App.
 */

    require('./server/routes')(app, db);

    server.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
        console.log("Server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
    });

    require('./server/sockets')(io, db);
```

Useful links
https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x
http://socket.io/#how-to-use

Comment: Thank you - I got mine working last night, but this is exactly the reference I needed/will use.